# An email can't have more than 1 sender error

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have an email service.
When sending an email to the email address that SF provided  :

sffdc@skuh7gi7z4fo72pt6h2o.1l-8dix.....apex.sandbox.salesforce.com

I need to check the "from address" and search for Leads Or Contacts that have the same email.

When finding them, I need to attach the email to the records, but I'm getting the following error :

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED,
>   An email can't have more than 1 sender.: [FromAddress]

That's my code:

```
 EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.MessageDate = Date.today();
    em.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
    em.Subject = email.subject;
    em.Status = '3';


    em.ToAddress = env.toAddress;

    try{
        insert em;
        System.debug('====> Created EmailMessage '+em.Id);
    }catch(Exception e){
        //TODO
    }


    List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND :email.fromAddress IN EMAIL FIELDS 
            RETURNING Contact(Name),Lead(Name,IsConverted)];

            List<Contact> searchContacts = (List<Contact>)searchList[0];
            List<Lead> searchLeads = (List<Lead>)searchList[1];
            List<EmailMessageRelation> emailMessageRelationList = new List<EmailMessageRelation>();
            EmailMessageRelation emr;



            for (Lead curLead : searchLeads) {
                if(!curLead.IsConverted){
                    emr = new EmailMessageRelation();
                    emr.emailMessageId = em.id;
                    emr.relationId = curLead.Id;
                    emr.relationType = 'FromAddress';
                    emailMessageRelationList.add(emr);
                }
                System.debug(curLead.Name);
            }
            for (Contact curContact : searchContacts) {
                    emr = new EmailMessageRelation();
                    emr.emailMessageId = em.id;
                    emr.relationId = curContact.Id;
                    emr.relationType = 'FromAddress';
                    emailMessageRelationList.add(emr);
                System.debug(curContact.Name);
            }

            if(emailMessageRelationList.size()>0){
                System.debug('EmailMessageRealtionList has records -> ' + emailMessageRelationList);
                try{

                    insert emailMessageRelationList;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    //TODO
                }
            }
```

Now I believe that if I will set only one EmailMessageRelation and I won't create new on every record, that will be ok, but I didn't find a way to insert EmailMessageRelation with many relations Ids...

Any help will be much appreciate.